# The problem is that it takes a long time to index web pages in emdadrodbar.ir?

Tags: google-maps, google-search-console

I have a website for car and tow services for passenger cars and services which includes assistance and assistance for damaged cars in the North
Only the pages I create will not be indexed for long.
Please do a check.
emdadrodbar.ir

I used the yoast plugin and registered my sitemap in Google Search Console, but it didn't change much.
Is there a better solution to get my pages indexed sooner?